# Best way for delete relations mysql (laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have to do this

> Query all the MailTask with non null value for the deleted_at column
> and physical delete it from the database, delete first his
> associations from the table MailTaskMailMessage

I have to remove the associated data first

***and I did this function***

```
        MailTask::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at')->with('mail_task_mail_message')->forceDelete();
```

but I think this is not so

**these are the relations in migrations**

```
Schema::create('mail_task_mail_message', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedInteger('type');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->decimal('value', 16, 2);
            $table->foreignId('mail_task_id')->constrained('mail_tasks')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('mail_message_id')->constrained('mail_messages')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**and this**

```
Schema::create('mail_tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->text('meo_data');
    $table->unsignedInteger('state')->default(0);
    $table->text('recipients_names');
    $table->text('recipients_emails');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('meo_id');
    $table->foreign('meo_id')->references('id')->on('meos')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

My code is okay? or is wrong?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cascade foreign key on your mail_task_mail_message table, so you only need to do:

```
MailTask::whereNotNull('deleted_at')->forceDelete();
```

You have to use forceDelete() to actually delete the register instead of just setting deleted_at column.

Comment: I want to clean data that I already deleted before (softDeletes), should I do a forceDelete?

Comment: yes.  forceDelete() will delete the register completely.  Will edit answer to reflect this.